# Ampscript Error when editing HTML TXT

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have some AMPscript that is working when I preview it against data in a Data Extension. No errors.

However, when I make an edit to the Ampscript content block, even if it's just a HTML TXT change to a word and nothing to do with the Ampscript, I get the below error.

ERROR:

> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an Trim function call. See inner exception for details.
>   Invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less than or equal to the row count.
>    Index Value: 1
>    Row Count: 0
>    Function: Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME", 0), 1)

Content Block:

```
<span><b>Snack Club order details:</b></span> 

%%[ 

var @XML, @nodes, @rowCount 
SET @XML = AttributeValue("XML")
SET @productRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@XML, "/root/ITEM", 0) ]%% 

%%[ 

for @j = 1 to RowCount(@productRows) do

    SET @productXML = Concat("<item>", Field(Row(@productRows, @j), "XML"), "</item>")
    SET @ITEMPRODUCTNAME = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMPRODUCTSKU = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_SKU", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMPRODUCTURL = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_URL", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMPRODUCTIMGURL = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_IMG_URL", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMQTY = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_QTY", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMSUBSCRIPTIONPRICE = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @ITEMTOTAL = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_TOTAL", 0), 1), "Value")) 
    SET @rowColor = Iif(Mod(@j,2) == 0, "#ffffff", "#efefef") 

]%% 

%%[next @j]%%

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Product</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Quantity</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Price</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Item Total</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="%%=v(@ITEMPRODUCTURL)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@ITEMPRODUCTIMGURL)=%%">%%=v(@ITEMPRODUCTNAME)=%%</span></span></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            %%=v(@ITEMQTY)=%%</td><td>
            $%%=v(@ITEMSUBSCRIPTIONPRICE)=%% Each</td><td>
            $%%=v(@ITEMTOTAL)=%%
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Shipping Address</span></b></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Order Subtotal*</span></b></span>
            <span>$%%ORDER_SUBTOTAL%%</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>%%SHIPPING_ADDRESS_1%% %%SHIPPING_ADDRESS_2%%</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Order Shipping</span></b></span>
            <span>$%%ORDER_SHIPPING%%</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>%%SHIPPING_ADDRESS_TOWN%%, %%SHIPPING_ADDRESS_STATE%% </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>%%SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ZIP%%</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: XML being passed]

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question.

Comment: Also, please update your question to include a sample of the XML payload that's getting parsed.  Hard to debug anything XML without a sample.

Comment: I'd also suggest utilizing the defensive coding practices that I outlined in your previous question about XML parsing: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247070/5202